# Nvidia driver not loaded?

Tags: drivers, nvidia

Things have been running fine on my desktop Ubuntu, with an uptime of over 40 days. The only real change seems to be the occasional apt update/full-upgrade. However, after needing to do a restart, I noticed that my fan controller script stopped working. Poking around, I found the following returned messages when invoking the following two commands:

nvidia-smi:

```
nvidia-smi has failed because it couldn't communicate with the nvidia driver
```

nvidia-settings:

```
nvidia driver not loaded
```

Going into the driver manager, I see nvidia-384 selected, though at the bottom, it mentions that no proprietary drivers are in use. I figured I'd try reinstalling 384. No luck.

It seems like the nvidia drivers failed to load. If I do "lshw -c video", the "configuration" line per GPU reads:

```
configuration: latency=0
```

On another, working system that is identical, but has yet to be restarted, it reads:

```
configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
```

Using nvidia-390 or nvidia-396 solves the driver loading problem and allows the fan controller script to work again, but it stops certain programs from working, due to known driver issues, leaving me stuck on 384 indefinitely.

EDIT: Oddly enough, "lsmod | grep nvidia" does show nvidia entries, so it seems like it is loaded after all. Not sure where the issue lies, then.

Comment: What driver issues are you talking about that stop certain programs from working?  What ways have you tried to install?  Have you used the `graphics-drivers` ppa?  Are you trying to use Cuda 9.1 with your installation?

Comment: The software I'm running uses OpenGL, so CUDA is not required. I do use the PPA. As for the first question, the logs of the relevant software do not specify why other versions don't work. It just shows that it fails to run while using those driver versions. I think I might wait for 18.04 to be released, then try reinstalling everything.